# Windows batch file scripting: how to get directory named with latest date (yyyy-mm-dd format)?

Tags: batch-file, batch, batch-processing

I have a directory with many subdirectories. Each subdirectory is named with the yyyy-mm-dd format. I'm writing a Windows batch file and I need to grab the directory name with the most recent date and put that string into a variable. The last modified dates were changed, so using the last modified timestamp isn't an option.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any chance you can consider upgrading to powershell instead of a batch file?   The `Sort-Object` commandlet would make this trivial.

Comment: @Zoredache that might work if I can make a call to PowerShell to grab the folder name and return it to the batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f %%d in ('dir /ad /o-n /b .') do (
  echo %%d
  goto break
)
:break
```

- /ad - Displays files with specified attributes. (D:  Directories)
- /o-n List by files in sorted order. (n: By name (alphabetic), -n: Prefix to - reverse order)
- /b Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
- goto break - jump out the loop to take only first

ps

- /o-d List by files in sorted order. (d: By date/time (oldest first), -d: Prefix to - reverse order)